# AngularJS Upgrade to Angular Hybrid with Grunt/Bower

Tags: angularjs, angular, gruntjs, systemjs

I have an older project that we want to add some more functionality to. It's a fairly big project so rewriting it is out of the question. I've been reading and following the Angular ngUpgrade guide to make the transition to be able to write Angular 2+ code and run it with my AngularJS application.

However, there are some things that I'm missing and I'm quite confused on what I need to do.

My team created the initial project using Grunt and Bower, looks like through a Yeoman generator. I've been following along in the [PhoneCat Upgrade Tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#phonecat-upgrade-tutorial) and I'm at the part where it says to "Install Angular into the project, along with the SystemJS module loader."

At this point I've looked into SystemJS a bit and what we have with our Bower/Grunt setup but am fairly confused.

So my question is, do I need to change my AngularJS application to use SystemJS before continuing with the Angular Upgrade, or can Grunt and SystemJS work together in some way?